# Post soap message over http to WCF service error 400

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I currently have 2 apps:

1. A WCF Service
2. A console app that fires a HTTP request to my WCF service

I want to send a SOAP message to my WCF service and parse the XML data returned from WCF service. I can successfully GET and POST using plain XML and this endpoint URL http://localhost:62147/Service1.svc/Http/ but with SOAP it is not working. I get the following error when sending the request.

**Exception**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

**WCF Service web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
                <endpoint address="Soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="Http" kind="webHttpEndpoint" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**WCF IService1**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    string GetData(string channel);
}
```

**Console app**

```
private static string HttpPost(string _postData)
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.BaseAddress = "http://localhost:62147/Service1.svc/Soap/";
        webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        webClient.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData");

        byte[] response = webClient.UploadData("GetData", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_postData));

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    }
}
```

**Soap message**
I copied this from the WCF Test Client.

```
const string soapMsg = @"
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
        <s:Header>
            <Action s:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</Action>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body>
            <GetData xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                <channel>1</channel>
            </GetData>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>";
```

Comment: try `<endpoint address="Soap" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />` instead of `<endpoint address="Soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />`. BasicHttpBinding is old binding, when available, go for wsHttpBinding

Comment: @tomassino Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was how the XML data was being attached to the request. This is the working example I have for WebGet. This also works for WebInvoke methods also, but of course, just need to modify the soap body with expected paramters

**Console app**

```
private static void TestGet()
{
    Console.WriteLine("[TestGet]\n");

    const string soapMsg = @"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""
            xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance""
            xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <TestGet xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" />
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

    PerformSOAPRequest(URL, "TestGet", soapMsg);
}

public static void PerformSOAPRequest(string _url, string _method, string xml_message)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", string.Format("http://tempuri.org/IService1/{0}", _method));
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml_message);

    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (Stream putStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        putStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
    }
}
```

**IService1 in WCF**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "/TestGet")]
    string TestGet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add encoding declaration:  inside your `soapMsg` as well.

```
const string soapMsg = @"
    <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
        <s:Header>
            <Action s:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</Action>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body>
            <GetData xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                <channel>1</channel>
            </GetData>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>";
```

<strike>You need to make GET request to your SOAP Service, you have decorated `GetData` method with `WebMethod` attribute and its default HTTP method is GET.</strike>

Try to use `DownloadString` method instead of `UploadData` because `UploadData` makes request using POST method by default. However, you will need to change attribute `WebInvoke`into [WebGet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have just tried that and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use HttpWebRequest and WebResponse instead of WebClient

```
    public static void PerformSOAPRequest(string xml_message)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:62147/Service1.svc/Soap/");
        webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData");
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml_message);

        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove lines from SOAP envelop :

```
<s:Header>
   <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</Action>
</s:Header>
```

it works for me ...